# How to factor a quartic equation whose coefficient has unknown parameters?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

i'm trying to see if a quartic equation I obtained can be factored into simpler forms, such as the product of two quadratics. The problem is that their coefficients are some complex expressions in terms of several parameters. I wonder how to do this factorization. Or is there any better way to see how the solutions look at? Maybe looking at the formulas for the closed-form solutions of a quadratic equation?

Here is a simplified version of the equation:

```
a1*t^4 + a2*t^3 + a3*t^2 + a4*t + a5
```

One of the coefficients is shown below to demonstrate their complexity:
[image]

The expression is attached below:

```
1/4 (n . Subscript[f, 1])^2 - 
 3/4 (Subscript[v, 3] . Subscript[f, 1])^2 + 
 t (n . Subscript[f, 1] Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[f, 1] + 
    n . Subscript[f, 1] Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[v, 3] Subscript[v,
       3] . Subscript[f, 1]) + 
 t^3 (-n . Subscript[f, 1] Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[f, 1] + 
    2 n . Subscript[f, 1] Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[f, 
      1] (Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[v, 3])^2 + 
    n . Subscript[f, 1] Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[v, 3] Subscript[v,
       3] . Subscript[f, 1]) + 
 t^2 (-(1/2) (n . Subscript[f, 1])^2 + (Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[f,
       1])^2 - 
    Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[f, 1] Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[v, 
      3] Subscript[v, 3] . Subscript[f, 1] - 
    1/2 (Subscript[v, 3] . Subscript[f, 1])^2) + 
 t^4 (1/4 (n . Subscript[f, 1])^2 - (n . Subscript[f, 
       1])^2 (Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[v, 3])^2 + (Subscript[v, 
       2] . Subscript[f, 1])^2 (Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[v, 3])^2 -
     Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[f, 1] Subscript[v, 2] . Subscript[v, 
      3] Subscript[v, 3] . Subscript[f, 1] + 
    1/4 (Subscript[v, 3] . Subscript[f, 1])^2)
```

where the dot represents inner product of two three-dimensional vectors, and $n$ is normal to $v_2$ and $v_3$; moreover, $f_1$ is a vector that is not normal to $n$.

Notice that all the vectors involved are unit vectors. An numerical example can be produced using the following code:

```
nNum = Normalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]]
v2Num = Normalize[Cross[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], nNum]]
v3Num = Normalize[Cross[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], nNum]]
f1Num = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]
{n, Subscript[v, 2], Subscript[v, 3], Subscript[f, 1]} = {nNum, v2Num,
   v3Num, f1Num}
```

Here is an example of the vectors::

```
{n, Subscript[v, 2], Subscript[v, 3], Subscript[f, 1]}={{-0.159132, -0.385389, -0.908929}, {-0.808778, 
  0.578873, -0.103846}, {-0.87546, 0.480643, -0.0505222}, {-0.471107, 
  0.714036, 0.725794}}
```

However, I'm not trying to see whether it can be factored for a given set of these values; instead, I want to see if the factorization is possible regardless of their specific values.

Comment: For general coefficients, there is the general solution only, with highest coefficient normalized to 1 try $$Solve[Subscript[a, #] & /@ Range[0, 4] . t^Range[0, 4] == 
   0 /. {Subscript[a, 4] -> 1}, t]$$

Comment: How can we know if it can be factored when you did not provide all coefficients? (in Mathematica code not image)

Comment: @azerbajdzan, please see the expression in the updated post; I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to simplify the process of solving this equation. Currently, I'm guessing that it might be factored as two quadratic polynomials, or it can be rewritten as a quadratic equation in terms of another quadratic polynomial, but don't have any clue yet.

Comment: Can you provide one explicit example of `f1, v2, v3, n`?

Comment: "However, I'm not trying to see whether it can be factored for a given set of these values; instead, I want to see if the factorization is possible regardless of their specific values." - Every polynomial can be factored into its roots. But not all polynomial can be factored over integers, rationals, or some extensions. Your polynomial cannot be factored into nothing simpler than roots given by general quartic formula. You can see it if you use random integer instead of random real and then use `Factor` on the polynomial.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, I'd like to mention that all the vectors are unit vectors for my case, though it seems not a big issue. It is possible that the said polynomial can't be factored, but I don't understand the point you make here. Could you explain a bit more how you reached the conclusion that "our polynomial cannot be factored into nothing simpler than roots given by general quartic formula"?

Comment: As I can see `f1` is not unit vector. For `n` you can use `{1, 0, 0}` instead of `{2, 0, 0}` in my example with the same effect. "Could you explain a bit more..." - You asked if the polynomial can be factored for all `n, v2, v3, f1` produced in your code, I provided you with one counter-example which cannot be factored, therefore the original polynomial cannot be factored too.

Comment: Why not just use Factor?

Comment: @ Daniel Lichtblau Factor can only work with polynomials containing no variables within the coefficients, while I want to see if such an symbolical factorization is possible.

Comment: @ azerbajdzan I'm not quite sure why  the possibility of the decomposition of the quartic into two quadratic in symbolic form necessarily conflicts with your example. I'll think about it.

Comment: Factor handles multivariate polynomials just fine.

Comment: @larry: I have made an update in my answer. If you do not care about complicated nested roots then all quartics can be factored, but I think it is not what you mean by factoring your polynomial. I guess you want some nice coefficients without roots, but it is impossible for your polynomial - just as it is impossible for my polynomial in the example.

Answer (score 1):

`tu` is the polynomial in the question and if you substitute the following you see that the polynomial cannot be factored into nothing simpler than roots in the form of genearal quartic formula which means that the original polynomial (without specific values) cannot be factored too.

```
tu /. {n -> {2, 0, 0}, Subscript[v, 2] -> {0, 1, 0}, 
  Subscript[v, 3] -> {0, 0, 1}, Subscript[f, 1] -> {1, 1, 2}}
% == 0 // Solve // ToRadicals

(*-2 + 2 t - 3 t^2 - 2 t^3 + 2 t^4*)
```

**Edit:**

Usually by saying a polynomial can be factored is meant this:

```
1 + 2 x - 3 x^2 - 2 x^3 + 2 x^4 == (-1 + x) (1 + x) (-1 - 2 x + 2 x^2) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

And usually by saying a polynomial cannot be factored is meant that it cannot be expressed as product of expressions with integers coefficients.

So even though the following polynomial cannot be factored over integers or rationals or any simple extensions it still can be factored, for example, as follows:

```
-2+2 x-3 x^2-2 x^3+2 x^4==1/8 (4 x^2+x (-2+2 Sqrt[5+2 (-19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)-2 (19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)])-Sqrt[(11+(667-24 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)+(667+24 Sqrt[97])^(1/3))]+(-19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)-(19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)-1) (4 x^2+x (-2-2 Sqrt[5+2 (-19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)-2 (19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)])+Sqrt[(11+(667-24 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)+(667+24 Sqrt[97])^(1/3))]+(-19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)-(19+2 Sqrt[97])^(1/3)-1)//FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

[image]

If you do not care about complicated nested roots then all quartics can be factored, but I think it is not what you mean by factoring your polynomial. I guess you want some nice coefficients without roots, but it is impossible for your polynomial - just as it is impossible for my polynomial in the example.